# How do update JSONB column array inside array using update statement

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I am working on postgresql `JSONB` column and i want to update `Array` inside `Array` here is my json looks like this

```
[
 {
"name": "Arjun",
"artList": [
  {
    "id": 34,
    "category": "Sports",
    "names": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "label": "Cricket"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "label": "Football"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "label": "Hockey"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 35,
    "category": "Entertainment",
    "names": [
      {
        "id": 101,
        "label": "Ancor"
      },
      {
        "id": 102,
        "label": "Comdey"
      },
      {
        "id": 103,
        "label": "Singer"
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

And requirement is to remove `Cricket` from `artList` for the category `Sports` Where name is **Arjun**.

This is what i tried so far but its not working

```
  UPDATE usr
 SET art = s.json_array
  FROM (
     SELECT
       jsonb_agg(
        elems
    ) as json_array
   FROM
    usr p,
    jsonb_array_elements(p.art) elems where   p.name ='Sports' and elems->>'label'<>'Cricket'
 ) s where name ='Arjun'
```

Comment: This would be so much easier and faster with normalized database design

Comment: @Stefanov.sm could you please elaborate the solution .

Comment: table `person`, table `personal_art` with foreign key `person_id` -> `person.id`, table `art_items` with a bridge table b/w it and `personal_art` to shape many to many relationship. Maybe table `category` and a foreign key in `personal_art`, `category_id` -> `category.id`. You may have a look at normalization, can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple nested `jsonb_build_object` calls:

```
update js set vals = (select jsonb_agg(case when (v -> 'name')#>>'{}' = 'Arjun' 
    then v ||  jsonb_build_object('artList', 
        (select jsonb_agg(case when (v1 -> 'category')#>>'{}' = 'Sports' 
             then v1 || jsonb_build_object('names', (select jsonb_agg(v2) 
         from jsonb_array_elements(v1 -> 'names') v2 
         where (v2 -> 'label')#>>'{}' != 'Cricket')) else v1 end) 
       from jsonb_array_elements(v -> 'artList') v1)) 
    else v end) 
 from jsonb_array_elements(vals) v)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a7TgjsxS)

Comment: its working fine ... could you please help me with update by category for e.g remove either `Entertainment` or `Sports`

Comment: like post update `[{"name":"Arjun","artList":[{"id":34,"category":"Sports","names":[{"id":11,"label":"Cricket"},{"id":12,"label":"Football"},{"id":13,"label":"Hockey"}]}]}]` this is what i want

Comment: After update query the it changes the structure of `jsonb` to `array` in `artList[0]` and i can't find `id` and `category` key values

Comment: @Jharokha Please see my recent edit.